# TFS 2018 Update List of Visual Studio versions on Visual Studio build action

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there no way short of updating the TFS 2018 to the Azure devops 2021 version to get the visual studio build action to show versions of Visual Studio past 2017? We are moving from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2022 on the developers boxes and the build box itself

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there no way short of updating the TFS 2018 to the Azure devops 2021 version to get the visual studio build action to show versions of Visual Studio past 2017?

I am afraid there is no out of box way way to do this at this moment.

The latest version of the Azure devops Server is Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.2, which is not support the Visual Studio 2022.

To resolve this issue, you could use the a pre-built extension that packages a copy of the current task versions from Azure DevOps (service) (The author is jessehouwing)：

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.visualstudio

And you could also installed Build Tools 2022 or Visual Studio 2022 and set the msbuild path (instead of the version) in the build task settings with your private agent:

[image]